# Elasticsearch access to local computer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasicsearch instance running on my server. I have to configure it in such a way that it's only accessible via my local computer's public IP. I tried changing `network.host:` to my local IP but its not working. can anyone tell me what m I doing wrong.

Comment: you are looking at netowork.host in a wrong way. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019852/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-in-elasticsearch-5-2-0-from-selected-devices-compu/42020369#42020369

Comment: So is there any way that I can achieve what I want ?

Comment: you want to secure it only to access your IP or you just want to enable remote access ?

Comment: only my local computer should be allowed.

Comment: @TusharChevulkar: On your server this is a job of a firewall or iptables rules, which denies all traffic from anywhere, but allows from your client ip-address.

Answer (score 1):

Then i can suggest you two things here.

1) Either you put [nginx reverse proxy](https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx) in front of your elasticsearch server and filter the ip address you want to allow to connect elasticsearch.

In nginx.conf file in /usr/local/nginx/conf/ , for more [info](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/)

```
location / {
  # block one workstation
  deny    192.168.1.1;
  # allow anyone in 192.168.1.0/24
  allow   192.168.1.0/24;
  # drop rest of the world 
  deny    all;
}
```

2) Or you can use [elastic shield plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/ip-filtering.html) which comes with X-pack and you can use IP filtering feature to restrict the access to your elasticcluster.

In elasticsearch.yml file

```
shield.transport.filter.allow: "192.168.0.1"
shield.transport.filter.deny: "192.168.0.0/24"
```

Also you can edit these settings using their REST api

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
    "persistent" : {
        "shield.transport.filter.allow" : "172.16.0.0/24"
    }
}'
```

read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/ip-filtering.html).
Thanks